# Prometheus metric value age

Tags: prometheus

Using the Prometheus blackbox exporter I'm wondering how to retrieve the "age" of a metric or value a.k.a "How long is the monitored service up?". I know that I can resolve this be writing my own exporter which carries a gauge metric for the related timestamps, but I wonder if I could use the existing functions somehow?

My setup....Prometheus scrape config:

```
scrape_configs:
- job_name: 'blackbox'
  scrape_interval: 120s
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  metrics_path: /probe

  params:
    module: [http_2xx]

  static_configs:
    - targets:
      - https://example.org
```

The related values can be queried with `up{job="blackbox"}` which brings up:

```
Element                                             Value
up{instance="https://example.org/",job="blackbox"}  1
```

What I'd love to do:

```
time()-last_change(up{instance="https://example.org/",job="blackbox"})
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a very metricy question, and so is hard to answer with Prometheus. Prometheus is more focused on overall state rather than an individual event, such as a scrape failure.

If the monitored service is instrumented with a Prometheus client library that supports it, `process_start_time_seconds` may do what you need.

Comment: Thanks - kind of confirms my findings. I choose the blackbox exporter example to avoid answers which point to a local state in the client. As I wrote, I know that I could keep this information in the client, but I'd prefer to solve it within Prometheus.

Comment: The way to think about it is that when the last network blip or whatever happened is uninteresting. What is of interest is the ratio of times it worked (`avg_over_time`), to confirm it is just the odd blip happening and that you're well within SLA.

Comment: I appreciate your help but disagree here slightly ... sometimes a developer or tester might wonder whether the strange thing he saw 10 seconds ago was due to his actions or due to some other well known thing... "Database was down 10 seconds ago, but that's allright as it happens not too often" ... I would not base alerts on that, but it is of interest in some cases.